# reading and analyzing txt files

Tags: arrays, vb.net, structure

Im trying to write up a code where two txt files are being compared to each other. One text files has the answer like "TFTTFFT" and the other txt files has the result including id like "1234 TT-FFT" The crazy part is that for each correct answer, the student gets 4 points and for every incorrect answer, the student gets -1 and for every no answer, which in this case is represented by a dash(-), the student gets zero. How do i go about writing up a code for this? ANy help will be very much appreciated. I don't necessarily need some one to code this for me as i have pretty much done the opening of files and storing them in appropriate variables. Just a feed back on how to go about doing this would be nice. Thank you in advance.

Update :
I have revised the whole code and will put it up for consideration. Thank you Josh and thank you all those who have contributed so far. Please do let me know further what you guys think of the revised coding.

Update : Program not working :(

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: How do i insert the code i have written so far? The comment box does not let me insert the code.

Comment: Edit your question and add it.  Use the code formatting button (or indent with four spaces) to get the correct formatting.

Comment: ok done. The codes i have reads the files from the text files and stores them in appropriate variables. Im not sure if the reading of the answer part in the btnAnswer procedure is done correctly.

Comment: Can you post a short sample of the first few lines of each of these files? Obviously with txt file parsing input format is crucially important.

Comment: How do i upload the text files in here?

Comment: Can you just open in notepad and paste into your question? Just a few lines of each will do.

Comment: answer file : TFTTTTTTFFTFTFTTTTFF

Comment: student responsefile                                              : 5
236499,TFTFTFTFFFFTFTFFFTF-
643828,TFTFTTTTTF--FTFTFTTF
917057,FTF-FTTTFFFTF-FTFTFT
656565,FTF-FTFTFTF-TTFT-TTT
183742,FFTF-FFT-TFFFTFTFTFF

Comment: studentDetail                                                          10
643828,Mary,Low,Samoa
123456,Milo,Thatch,Fiji
917057,Filo,Fill,Tonga
656565,Mary,Runaway,Fiji
183742,Cat,Women,Vanuatu
236499,John,Noo,Fiji
129856,Ray,Sting,Solomons
258796,Shrek,Nice,Tuvalu
345871,Dan,Coyote,Vanuatu
414141,Ben,Foo,Samoa

Comment: @El Ronnoco hi, still waiting on your response

Comment: Hi, can you actually post that into the question please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim answers As String = 'Text from the answor file
    Dim student As String = 'Text from the student file

    ' a will be used to hold the first char from the answers file
    ' s will be used to hold the first char from the student file
    Dim a As String
    Dim s As String

    ' veriable that holds the student grad
    Dim grade As Integer = 0

    ' loop while we still have an answer
    While answers.Length > 0

        ' get the first answer and student respond
        a = answers.First
        s = student.First

        ' compare the two and update the student grade accourdingly
        If a = "-" Then
            grade = grade - 1

        ElseIf a = s Then
            grade = grade + 4
        Else
            grade = grade - 1
        End If

        ' remove the first answer from the two strings
        answers = answers.Substring(1)
        student = student.Substring(1)
    End While


    return grade
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I am assuming you are just getting started in programming I'll share some advice and a general approach to solving the problem.

The most important skill you will need to develop as a programmer is to be able to break a complex problem down into simple and easy to digest chunks. As I see it this problem has 3 discrete parts to it. I'll try to express these in pseudo code.

### Reading and parsing the files

```
Open (Answer Key File)

Read All Text From (Answer Key File) into (String)

Convert (String) into array of characters as (Answer Key Array)

Close (Answer Key File)

Open (Student's File)

Read All Text From (Student's File) into (String)

Extract (Student ID) from (String)

Extract (Student's Answers) from (String)

Convert (Student's Answers) to Character Array as (Student Answers Array)

Close (Student's File)
```

### Comparing the student's answers to the key and calculating the student's score

```
Set (Student Score) equal to '0'

FOR EACH (Answer) in (Student's Answers Array)

   Get (Key) from (Answer Key Array) at (Current Loop Index)

   IF (Answer) equals [NO_ANSWER] THEN
      Continue

   IF (Answer) equals (Key) THEN
      Add 4 to (Student Score)
   ELSE
      Subtract 1 from (Student Score)
```

Your entire program should only contain a couple of methods. Anything more complicated and you are over thinking it ;)

Remember it helps to go through this exercise for any of your programs. Even better, write these out as comments in your source file and then fill in the necessary code. You'll be amazed how quickly you get done.

Comment: Thank you Josh. I believe i did get the first portion right in  my code (reading and parsing the files) but im still struggling to implement the next part ie comparing and calculating. Ill give it a shot again and if im still unsuccessful, i would surly get back to this forum :)

Comment: Sorry guys, im still pretty much confused. Josh i tried what you recommended but still unsuccessful.

Comment: I'm not sure about the 'only contain a couple of methods' part. That may be a little low on methods and I think if, given the OP's apparent skill level, he tries to stick to that constant, he may end up with some cumbersome, overly long methods.

Comment: @ElRonnoco - You need a method for reading the answer, one for reading the student file, and one for calculating the score. My intention is not to burden him with that constraint, but to give him a guide. If he finds himself writing a bunch of code then he is over complicating the issue. Seeking simplicity is a skill he needs to learn, and it needs to start early. Far too many developers today simply code through problems because that is how they learned how.